CloudFormation doesn't care about the custom resource lambda failure
I'm trying to deploy a custom resource using the CDK.
The following is the lambda code that is triggered by CloudFormation

export const handler = async (
    event: Partial<CdkCustomResourceEvent> | undefined,
): Promise<CdkCustomResourceResponse> => {
    const logger = pino();

    logger.info({ event }, "event2");

    const baseResponse: CdkCustomResourceResponse = {
        StackId: event?.StackId,
        RequestId: event?.RequestId,
        LogicalResourceId: event?.LogicalResourceId,
        PhysicalResourceId: "editor-db-schema-migrator",
    };

    return {
        ...baseResponse,
        Status: "FAILED",
        Reason: "terrible error",
        Data: {
            Result: new Error("TROLOLOLO"),
        },
    };
};


And the following is the CDK code that actually deploys the lambda:
const functionName = "editor-db-schema-migrator";

        const onEventHandler = new Function(this, "MigratorFunction", {
            functionName,
            description:
                "Lambda function running the Editor Database schema migrations during the deployment process.",
            runtime: LAMBDA_RUNTIME,
            code: Code.fromAsset(join(LAMBDA_DIR, functionName)),
            handler: `${functionName}.handler`,
            logRetention: getConfig().logs.logsGroupRetentionDays,
            role: getDefaultLambdaRole(this, "MigrationFunctionRole", { functionName }),
            vpc: props.vpc,
            securityGroups: props.securityGroups,
        });

        const provider = new Provider(this, "CustomResourceProvider", {
            onEventHandler,
            logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_DAY,
            providerFunctionName: "EditorDbSchemaMigratorProvider",
        });

        new CustomResource(this, "EditorDbSchemaMigratorCustomResource", {
            resourceType: "Custom::EditorDbSchemaMigrator",
            serviceToken: provider.serviceToken,
            properties: {
                test: "10",
            },
        });

Now, I can see that the lambda is actually triggered during the deployment, however, even though I'm returning the "FAILED" status, CloudFormation continues with the deployment as if nothing happened. I need it to fail. What am I missing here?
